# python to extract and modify data from/to .txt file

Tags: python, file, edit

I have to a binary txt file that's created by `xxd command` and i want to change only the binary contents in a specific manner(some logical bit wise operation).

This is the file content of "1.txt"

```
0000000: 01010000 01001011 00000011 00000100 00010100 00000011  PK....

0000006: 00000000 00000000 00001000 00000000 11010111 10111011  ......

000000c: 10010110 01000101 00010011 11010111 01000010 01110110  .E..Bv

0000012: 11011101 00001011 00000000 00000000 10001110 00001110  ......

0000018: 00000000 00000000 00001001 00000000 00000000 00000000  ......

000001e: 01110100 01100101 01110011 01110100 00101110 01100100  test.d

0000024: 01101111 01100011 01111000 10001101 01010111 00000111  ocx.W.

000002a: 01010000 00010011 01101001 00011000 00100101 10110100  P.i.%.

0000030: 01010000 00100101 10000100 00000000 01010010 10100100  P%..R.

0000036: 10000011 01001000 00001111 01000111 10010111 01100010  .H.G.b

000003c: 11101000 11100101 00001110 11101001 10100000 01110100  .....t

0000042: 10100100 11110111 00100110 01000101 10001000 10000000  ..&E..

0000048: 01010010 10010100 10101000 00001000 10000010 00001000  R.....

000004e: 00001010 10000100 01110000 11000010 10100001 10000100  ..p...
```

**what i want is(In Steps as follows):**

1. to create another file(dump.txt) and place all the binary contents
   from the above file like as follows:

   ```
   01010000 01001011 00000011 00000100 00010100 00000011

   00000000 00000000 00001000 00000000 11010111 10111011

   10010110 01000101 00010011 11010111 01000010 01110110

   11011101 00001011 00000000 00000000 10001110 00001110

   00000000 00000000 00001001 00000000 00000000 00000000

   01110100 01100101 01110011 01110100 00101110 01100100

   and so on . . . . . till end of the original(1.txt)
   ```
2. Do some logical operations.(This part has been taken care) *For example say converted all binary values to 1's* and places it inside "dump2.txt"
3. place the modified contents from above step(dump2.txt) instead of the original
   contents. That is i want to edit the original(1.txt) file content by
   replacing values(from dump2.txt) created from previous step(2). so it
   looks like as follows..

   ```
   0000000: 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111  PK....

   0000006: 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111  ......

   000000c: 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111  .E..Bv

   0000012: 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111  ......

   0000018: 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111  ......

   000001e: 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111  test.d

   0000024: 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111  ocx.W.
   ```

**My question is**

- using python how do i extract only the middle section to another file(so i can manipulate the contents).
- and how do i place the modified contents back into the same file(instead of the original content).

**my 1st try was:**

```
infile = "1.txt"
outfile = open("dump.txt", "w")

with open(infile, 'r') as contents:
    #for line in contents:
        line = contents.readline()
        for i in range(1,7):
            outfile.write(line.split()[i])

outfile.close()
```

this generated output as

```
010100000100101100000011000001000001010000000011
```

i know, the first for loop was not proper to fetch each and every line one after the other,
the error i got while nu-commenting was

```
ValueError: Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data
```

**My 2nd try was:**

```
import StringIO 
import re

infile = "2.txt"
outfile = open("dump.txt", "w")
match = re.compile(ur': (.*?)  ')

with open(infile, 'r') as contents:
    line_infile = contents.readline()
    while line_infile:
        outfile.write(re.findall(match, line_infile))
        line_infile = contents.readline()
outfile.close()
```

im getting an error saying

```
    outfile.write(re.findall(match, line_infile))
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

I dont know how to place the regex expression inside another statement(inside file.write()).
can anyone please help...

Comment: what did you try so far ?

Comment: @aberna i tried to read individual lines using readline() within in for loop. then .split()[1],.... to .split()[6] with in another for loop. all i ended up was some bunch of lists style display inside another textfile

Comment: `outfile.write()` expects a character buffer whereas `re.findall` returns a list, you need to convert that list into a character buffer and you will not have the `TypeError`.

Comment: @aberna im new to python,.. can you explain with an code example about how to handle and make use of character buffer.

Comment: @arvindh your question is for the user Adeeb. In any case I would suggest you to make better usage of SO. Start from the error message "TypeError: expected a character buffer object", search if anyone in SO have already faces and solved this issue.

Comment: okay, i vl create an separate and individual post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do, you can express your computation using a single loop

```
for line in contents:
    outfile.write(''.join(line.split()[1:7])
```

About the `ValueError` you get when you uncomment, it is because the statement

```
for line in contents:
```

expresses a sequence of lines to be read from `contents` and then you are trying to read
a line from `contents`: this confuses the interpreter.

Comment: I tried what you have mentioned above by replacing line 5 to 8 with your 2 lines of code.but im getting syntax error at the line outfile.close() And thanks a lot for your explanation about the error. i got it now. and im really sorry if my question isn't clear. i have edited my question. plz do help me out @gboffi